# htaccess, create false path inside path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I Want to create a false subdirectory path in directory

ORIGINAL URL:

> http://localhost/abracadabra/?doce=1&travessura=9

CURRENT URL (MY HTACCESS):

> http://localhost/abracadabra/1/9

I WANT:

> http://localhost/abracadabra/1/permalink/9

"permalink", i want this false path

CURRENT HTACCESS:

> RewriteRule ^abracadabra/([^/]*)$ /abracadabra/index.php?doce=$1 [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^abracadabra/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$
>   /abracadabra/index.php?doce=$1&travessura=$2 [L]

Comment: Please post your current htaccess and attempts you've made.

Comment: cleared my all attempts ;-;

Comment: Cleared all attempts? Meaning you have resolved it?

Comment: no, i try all attempts i ve found in google, but all fail

Comment: Have you been already using `rewrite` conditions for the current URL that you've mentioned in the question?

Comment: YES;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

Comment: Can you post that so that I can derive a solution from that for the one you want?

Comment: okay, i edited with my atual code

Comment: You want to have both current URL and the one you want from the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^abracadabra/([^/]*)$ /abracadabra/index.php?doce=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^abracadabra/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /abracadabra/index.php?doce=$1&travessura=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^abracadabra/([0-9]+)/permalink/([0-9]+)$ /abracadabra/index.php?doce=$1&travessura=$2 [L]
```

Hope it helps!